# Pour tous nombres A et B ?

Tags: pluriel, mathématiques

En mathématiques, on utilise souvent l'expression "pour tout", par exemple :

> Pour tout nombre entier N, il existe un nombre entier N+1.

Dans ce contexte, la proposition suivante est-elle correcte ?

> Pour tous nombres A et B, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui, le pluriel de ***tout*** est ***tous*** donc :

> *Pour **tous** nombres A et B, il existe un nombre C...*

Comme la prononciation est ici identique, on rencontrera parfois l'incorrect *<s>pour tout nombres</s>...*

Answer (score -2):

Oui, elle est correcte. On peut aussi dire « Pour tous les nombres A et B, … » ou « Donnés tous nombres A et B, … » et même « Pour tout nombre A et tout nombre B, … ».

---

Complément dû au commentaire de user **[anderstood](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41308/pour-tous-nombres-a-et-b/41309?noredirect=1#comment83260_41309)**

Je ne peux pas trouver une référence pour « Donné une droite, un plan, un triangle, etc. » ; c'est une généralisation  qui me semble sans problème et c'est pour cela que je la mentionne. On trouve par exemple ceci : (http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~jroyer/TD/2016-17-L1PS/L1PS-16-Ch1.pdf)  « Étant donnés deux ensembles » ; on trouve ailleurs « Étant données deux assertions ». Donc qu'il s'agisse de nombres ou d'entités géométriques cela n'a aucune importance. Je ne vois pas ce qui empêche le passage à la forme simple non plus, puisque « étant » est optionnel : https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-106776.php.

On utilise très couramment « soit » pour les nombres, qui est entièrement synonyme à « donné » et qui sans modification du nom qui suit, même pas par le redondant « quelconque » signifie « n'importe lequel » « quel qu'il soit » ou encore « tout ». Dans le cas  de deux nombres on fera l'accord : « Soient deux nombres A et B, … ».

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104870/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-pour-tous-nombres-a-et-b).